# puppeteer / spatie/Browsershot click a specific attribute

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, google-crawlers, browsershot

***Updated QUESTION** (original below is no longer reproduceable):* I'm working with spatie/Browsershot to fill a web form. I'm able to get past the first page:

```
Browsershot::url('https://www.homedepotrebates11percent.com/#/home')
        ->newHeadless()
        ->setNodeBinary('/usr/bin/node')
        ->setNpmBinary('/usr/bin/npm')
        ->setChromePath('/usr/bin/chromium-browser')
        ->waitUntilNetworkIdle()
        ->type('#purchaseDateOnlyText', '09/19/2023)
        ->click('#home-offer-purchasedate-continue2')
        ->delay(1000);
```

The second page has a "Continue" button `id="continueOrSubmitBtn"` which I was able to select in the past but now the Continue Button html looks like this and I'm unable to select it:

```
<div ng-if="!hideContinue" class="ng-scope">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 pull-right">
        <div ng-switch="continueType"><!-- ngSwitchWhen: address --><!-- ngSwitchDefault:  -->
            <div ng-switch-default="" class="ng-scope"><a id="continueOrSubmitBtn" ng-disabled="!!disabledWhen"
                    ng-click="disabledWhen || navigationCtrl.next()" class="btn btn-primary cont" tabindex="0"
                    href="javascript:void(0)"><!-- ngIf: pageWorkflow.submitPage -->
                    <!-- ngIf: !pageWorkflow.submitPage --><span ng-if="!pageWorkflow.submitPage"
                        class="ng-binding ng-scope">Continue <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"
                            aria-hidden="true"></span></span><!-- end ngIf: !pageWorkflow.submitPage --></a></div>
            <!-- end ngSwitchWhen: -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

To reproduce:
https://www.homedepotrebates11percent.com/#/home
Date = 09/19/2023
Continue
"Promotion Details" page shows with the Continue Button active.


Any idea how I can click/select that Continue buttom?

Thanks! Patryk

***ORIGINAL QUESTION:*** I'm working with spatie/Browsershot to fill a web form. I'm able to get past the first page:

```
Browsershot::url('https://www.homedepotrebates11percent.com/#/home')
        ->newHeadless()
        ->setNodeBinary('/usr/bin/node')
        ->setNpmBinary('/usr/bin/npm')
        ->setChromePath('/usr/bin/chromium-browser')
        ->waitUntilNetworkIdle()
        ->type('#purchaseDateOnlyText', '09/19/2023)
        ->click('#home-offer-purchasedate-continue2')
        ->delay(1000);
```

The second page has, what looks like a radio group, and I need to select a specific one before continuing. The code for one of the selects:

```
<div class="panel panel-default ng-scope sel" ng-repeat="promo in promoSelectCtrl.promotions" ng-click="promoSelectCtrl.select($index)" ng-class="{sel: $index == promoSelectCtrl.selected}" style="">
    <div class="select-text panel-heading">
        <span class="fa fa-check-circle" ng-class="($index == promoSelectCtrl.selected) ? 'fa-check-circle' : 'fa-circle-thin'" aria-hidden="true" style="">
        </span><div id="selectRebate" translate="content.SELECT_SELECT_REBATE_TEXT" class="ng-scope">SELECT THIS REBATE</div></div><div class="panel-body promo-descr">
            <div class="row"><div class="col-md-12">
                <!-- ngIf: !promoSelectCtrl.isDisplayCampaignWebDescription -->
                <p ng-if="!promoSelectCtrl.isDisplayCampaignWebDescription" id="11% Rebate - Valid Only on Purchase Dates 08/28/2023 - 09/24/2023" class="ng-scope">
                    <strong translate="content.PC2_23_16661_NAME" translate-default="11% Rebate - Valid Only on Purchase Dates 08/28/2023 - 09/24/2023" class="ng-scope">
                        11% Rebate - Valid Only on Purchase Dates 08/28/2023 - 09/24/2023
                    </strong>
                </p>
                <!-- end ngIf: !promoSelectCtrl.isDisplayCampaignWebDescription -->
                <!-- ngIf: promoSelectCtrl.isDisplayCampaignWebDescription --><!-- ngIf: !hidePurchaseDates -->
                <p ng-if="!hidePurchaseDates" class="ng-binding ng-scope">Purchase Dates: 08/28/2023 - 09/24/2023</p>
                <!-- end ngIf: !hidePurchaseDates --><!-- ngIf: submitby --><!-- ngRepeat: (key, value) in promo.additionalData -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

To reproduce:
https://www.homedepotrebates11percent.com/#/home
Date = 09/19/2023
Continue
list of the radio group should be shown on page.


Any idea how I can click on one of these radio buttons(that are not really radio buttons?).

Thanks! Patryk

[Edit 1]:
For reference this is what the page in question looked like:
[image]

Comment: Hi, I was hoping someone would have some insights. This is a very repetitive and manual task for us that we were able to automate in the past but unsure how to target this new `ng-*` this site is throwing at us.

Comment: Do you still have that selection? After selecting the date on the home page and clicking "continue" I'm taken to the "Promotion Details" page where there's only one offer, no pseudo-radio buttons, the continue button is active and clicking on it takes me to "Purchase information"

Comment: I can not reproduce it, please add a screenshot to show where is the `radio group`.

Comment: @kikon it went away to the way it used to be! It saves me a headache. I will reach back out if it ever comes back. Maybe it's something they're testing. I will post back when I see it again. Thanks for your replies

Comment: Is it possible that there's only one promotion active now and when they'll add another one that screen will just appear? Anyway, please move the printscreen from the answer section to the question (by editing your question) - if it's not an answer it will be deleted.

Comment: It's possible but last week is the first time I saw it. The date in my example, 9/19/2023 would bring up the 3 promotions regardless of when the query is made. (Assuming since offer #1 and #3 are valid 4/2023 - 1/2024. Offer #2, the one im after is valid 8/28/23 - 9/24/23.

Comment: @kikon - ok. The entire workflow has changed. I updated my question above that you should be able to reproduce now. The Continue button you mention in your first comment on The Promotion Details page IS active. However, in the past I was able to target it by id = "continueOrSubmitBtn". It seems to no longer work with error of "continueOrSubmitBtn"

Comment: Yes, it does work with `#continueOrSubmitBtn`, it's  the `<a id="continueOrSubmitBtn"` inside those divs, that you may click to get to the "Promotion Details" page; maybe replace `->delay(1000)` with another `->waitUntilNetworkIdle()`

Comment: I've tried it a few separate ways with no result. Getting "Error: No element found for selector: #continueOrSubmitBtn at assert". I'm sure I'm past the first page because I'm able to print the 2nd page with the ``` #continueOrSubmitBtn```

Comment: Hi, so I still can't figure out why I'm unable to select `id="continueOrSubmitBtn"` there are attributes on that a tag:  `ng-disabled="!!disabledWhen"
                    ng-click="disabledWhen || navigationCtrl.next()"` could this be the reason why I get the " Error: No element found for selector: #continueOrSubmitBtn at assert" if so, how can i make the `continueOrSubmitBtn` selector active?

Comment: Hi again - so I think the issue is that I need to use the puppeteer stealth plugin but I'm having trouble implementing it with Browsershot. https://github.com/spatie/browsershot/pull/399 Any idea how I can do so?